# Jasig CAS: Monitoring authenticated users

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, jasig

I am trying to use JASIG CAS as SSO for several webapps. I've managed to setup a custom configuration (maven overlay) and "casify" a couple of webapps. Nevertheless, I'd like to add some monitoring functions such as:

- List authenticated users: IP, principal identity
- Expire a session user
- List which applications is the user signed on

Is there anything similar to this in JASIG CAS out of the box?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention the CAS version you are using, this answer covers  version 4.1.

I think the closest thing out of the box is:

### SSO Sessions Report

CAS also provides a /statistics/ssosessions endpoint that produces a report of all active non-expired SSO sessions. The output of this endpoint is a JSON representation of SSO sessions that is rendered into a modest visualization.

By default, ticket-granting ticket ids are not shown. This behavior can be controlled via cas.properties:

```
##
# Reports
#
# Setting to whether include the ticket granting ticket id in the report
# sso.sessions.include.tgt=false
```

Link:
http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.1.x/installation/Monitoring-Statistics.html#sso-sessions-report

Comment: Currently I'm using CAS 3.5. Thank you for your tip. It's time to migrate to CAS 4.

Comment: Thanks, for selecting my answer!